Qiskit's Integer Comparator
Does the IntegerComparator from qiskit.circuit.library works fine, or am I doing something wrong in understanding it's working?
I'm working with this simple comparison circuit. Im comparing the 011 (3) with integer value 4, with this code
from qiskit.circuit.library import IntegerComparator
size = 3 # size of the state register
value = 4 # value to compare with

comp = IntegerComparator(size, value, geq=True)

from qiskit.circuit import QuantumCircuit
circ = QuantumCircuit(2*size,1)

# add x gates here 
circ.x(0)
circ.x(1)

circ.append(comp, range(2*size))
#circ.measure(range(size), range(size))
circ.measure(size,0)
circ.draw('mpl',fold=-1)

and then, I run it using the sampler
result = sampler.run(circ, shots=1024).result()
counts = result.quasi_dists[0]
print(counts)

I'm getting 1 as an output, which is incorrect, as $ 3 \ngeq 4$.
Am I doing something wrong in my understanding?

You are misinterpreting the results. The code you provided returns a dictionary of the form {0: 1.0}. This means you are measuring a 0 with probability of 1.0.

Thanks, I migrated the code to qiskit 1.0 and using sampler result, and it showed this as a result.
